# Using a custom view for a menu item in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view

I am having a problem using custom view for menu item in Android, I know this has been answered many times but my case is sort of unique.
my menu has only one item, then there is another menu with many items under this root item
I am trying to use custom view on the item in sub menu. but I always get 'this is title' instead of 'this is custom view'

my menu xml is like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="always">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/new_menu_item"
                app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_layout"
                app:showAsAction="always"
                android:title="this is title" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

my custom view menu_item_layout looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="this is custom view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried to call setActionView on new_menu_item in code but still doesn't work, added app:showAsAction="always" didn't help, flipped between app:actionLayout and android:actionLayout also didn't help